# Gitlab pipeline stuck with nx cloud issue

Tags: unit-testing, build, gitlab-ci, node-modules, nomachine-nx

I have tried run pipeline from last one week. But this is not working fine. Is there any issues here? Before last week this pipeline is working perfectly. Now this is stuck with this error.

````
 >  NX   Took longer than 3 seconds to hear from heartbeat process
   The heartbeat process may have not started properly. This CIPE could have inconsistent status reporting.
 >  NX   Nx Cloud: Workspace is disabled
   This Nx Cloud organization has been disabled due to exceeding the FREE plan.
   An organization admin can start a free PRO plan trial for up to two months with no billing required at https://cloud.nx.app/orgs/63c038302fe9b1000ec9a7d0/plans
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /builds/pipeline/qa-alps/coverage/**/**/cobertura-coverage.xml: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/pipeline/qa-alps/) ```
 

 [![pipeline-issue][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs9Up.png
````